# Populate Select Box with Clickable Links

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, drop-down-menu, server-side

I have a PHP, JS, AJAX app that I am trying to finish off.
I have a select box that populates from the files in a server-side folder.
Works okay but I am trying to make the select box options clickable or on hover.
A better solution might be to use AJAX to contact a PHP little page that provides a list of files in JSON to be given back to the JavaScript, and have this AJAX run when triggered by a hover listener 
I don't know enough php syntax to get it working and have tried many methods (well one, but different variations on it), the most recent is in the comments.
Ideally I would also like it to only populate by  file name , in the format year-month-day, in descending order.
This is the code I have. Very grateful for any assistance.

Tried what is in the comments and many variations.

```
<?php
$files = scandir('upload/');
sort($files);
echo "<select>";
foreach($files as $file){
   //echo'<a href="upload/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>'";
   echo "<option value=' $file'> $file </option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

For anyone that is interested this is all working now.
I made quite a few changes to the correct/accepted answer.
The code is as follows:

The css (I wanted the drop-down button look like a standard/default button so removed css for it):

```
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
```

The php, jquery and ajax:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" id="file-browser">Latest Timesheet</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="file-list">

<?php
  $files = array_slice(scandir('upload/'), 2);
  rsort($files);
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    $file = pathinfo($file)['filename'];
     echo "<a href='upload/$file'>$file</a>";
}  
?>
</div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#file-browser").hover(
  function (e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "my_dropdown_data.php",
    dataType: "json",    
    success: function(response) {    
      $("#file-list").html(""); //Clear current file list
      response.forEach(
        function(file) {
           $("#file-list").append("<a href='upload/" + file + "'>" + file.substr(0, file.length - 4) + "</a>");
        }
      );
    },
    error: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
    })
  }
);
</script>
```

The external php file (my_dropdown_data.php):

```
<?php
  $files = array_slice(scandir('upload/'), 2);
  rsort($files);
  echo json_encode($files);
?>
```

Comment: I think you'll need to clarify what you mean by clickable - by default `<option>`s are selectable. Do you want something to immediately happen without waiting for the form to send off? Are you trying to make a drop down menu with a `<select>`?

Comment: I messed up a bit on what i posted. I want the drop-down menu to be populated with just the jpg files in the upload folder. these need to be clickable links. Ideally it would not show the folders like it does not either eg. links to ./ and ../

Comment: as it is it gets populated with the file names but no href so not clickable. If this is even possible. So selecting an item in the drop down would open the jpeg files.

Comment: It is possible, you can have to form not truly submit, run some JavaScript which gets the `<option>`s value and redirects you to that location. However, there are [many](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp), [many](https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/), [many](https://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/RNeydj) better ways to do it than with JS and a `<select>` menu :) If you'd like an example of the former, then I can write out an answer.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was looking at JavaScript but thinking it was client side did not think it could get list of files on server. I thought I was nearly there with the php code I have (maybe missing the correct formatting, a . or ' or " here and there). I had it working as a list of files outside of a drop-down but could not get it working inside.

Comment: You will need PHP or something of the like to list out files on the server, but you'll need client-side code to interact with a `<select>` list as you are intending. It would be significantly easier I think to follow a guide on a standard drop-down menu and list out files like that, but if your use-case requires, then your use-case requires.

Comment: Ah OK that makes sense. So I use my php code  (or different php code) that gets the file list from the server and then somehow use JavaScript to populate the drop down? Do you have a link to an example or a guide please?

Comment: I'll provide an answer after my commute.

Comment: Ceers zbee that will be most appreciated. In the mean time I will see if I can somehow figure it out. All part of the learning curve. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of the dropdown menu from the [guide from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp) as well as your own code. This is an alternative to using a `<select>` menu and having to build out a bit of JavaScript to make it work similar to a dropdown menu, which would be poor practice.

**!!!** *One note before anything*, this is directly taking from file names stored in your uploads directory. If you do not properly sanitize / randomize file names that are being uploaded, it's possible a user could escape this HTML and set up an XSS attack - please care for the file names on upload to avoid this.

You'll first set up the base HTML structure, this is what will be used for an asynchronous, reloading dropdown menu:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" id="file-browser">Dropdown Menu ACTIVATE</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="file-list">
  </div>
</div>
```

And now you'll fill in the data for a static, not reloading dropdown menu:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown Menu ACTIVATE</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">

  <?php
  $files = scandir('upload/');
  sort($files);
  foreach ($files as $file)
     echo "<a href='upload/$file'>$file</a>";
  ?>

  </div>
</div>
```

And finally, you have your CSS, directly from w3schools - these are the important bits to build off of:

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Now to get it to load data dynamically, you don't have to load the data initially since it will just be overwritten, but we do need a listener for when the button is hovered over (and the dropdown should be shown). That will be accomplished with jQuery's [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$("#file-browser").hover(
  function {

  }
);
```

Now we want to load the data, which we'll do utilizing AJAX; more specifically jQuery's [`.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$("#file-browser").hover(
  function {
    url: "my_dropdown_data.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {

    },
    error: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  }
);
```

The data will come from the file `my_dropdown_data.php` from above, and that will be essentially the same code from the static data dropdown, except echoed out as JSON:

```
  <?php
  $files = scandir('upload/');
  sort($files);
  echo json_encode($files);
  ?>
```

And the final piece of the puzzle will be all the JS -hover listener, AJAX call- with processing of the data to list out the JSON list of files from our PHP:

```
$("#file-browser").hover(
  function {
    url: "my_dropdown_data.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      $("#file-list").html(""); //Clear current file list
      response.forEach(
        function(file) {
          $("#file-list").append("<a href='upload/" + file + "'>" + file + "</a>");
        }
      );
    },
    error: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  }
);
```

And voila, there you have your dropdown menu, and when hovered over the data will load from the PHP file and populate the dropdown with links to the files.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Works a treat on my test page. Fantastic :) Just have to integrate it into the live one. I changed the first line of the php to *$files = array_slice(scandir('upload/'), 2);*, to remove the ./ and ../ directories. Only one thing I might need. The file name is spread over 2 lines. How would I make it so it fits on one line.

Comment: Ah I just noticed it does not dynamically update like it would with javascript I think?). I have to refresh the page

Comment: Probably make `.dropdown-content` have a `min-width` attribute, or setting the `white-space` attribute.

Comment: Correct, it only reloads the data on page load. To make it dynamically refresh that will be an entirely separate element of setting up AJAX to contact a PHP little page that provides a list of files in JSON to be given back to the JavaScript, and have this AJAX run when triggered by a hover listener - a little bit more complex. I think that's outside of the scope of the current question, if you edit the question to include that or make a new one I can provide an answer for that.

Comment: wow thanks that would be amazing. I like this very much and will use it elsewhere but it does not quite fit with what I am trying to achieve here. I will edit the question shortly. Cheers :)

Comment: @flakie Do you have jQuery already, or do you prefer straight JS for this?

Comment: @flakie Have a look, let me know

Comment: Unfortunately the auto-refresh of the drop-down does not work for me :(  -  I am assuming that the "final piece of the puzzle" code gets wrapped in its own script tags, separate to the static data code?. I have tested this by deleting files from the upload folder via ftp ad then hovering over the drop-down. Anyway, I think you have spent far too much time on this for me, for which I am very grateful. I will try and see if I can find a way  to resolve it. if not able I will just have it as a static list and refresh the browser to update. Thanks again for all your time and effort.

Comment: Actually Firefox and Chrome debuggers both find an issue with line 39 of the code. this is the function part form the following code: $("#file-browser").hover(
  function {  -  Firefox states: SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters whereas Chrome states: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: I now have this working. Simple in the end but someone had to put me on the right track. The ajax call was missing from the code so I added it in and all if good. Also had to put an (e) in the first function. Thanks very much for the code. Now I just have to work out how to trim the loop so it does not display the extension part of the file name in the list. Some how get this into the existing code (I am working on it with little success so far): trim($file, '.jpg');

Comment: Sorted it for the main dynamic part: $("#file-list").append("<a href='upload/" + file + "'>" + file.substr(0, file.length - 4) + "</a>");